# Migration from CXF 2.7.0 to JAX-RS 2.0 (RestEasy 3.0.1 precisely)

Tags: java, cxf, jax-rs, jboss7.x, resteasy

I have a library written using CXF which is used old applications and running in tomcat. I am now using that library for a new application hosted in JBoss AS 7. Hence I am rewriting the CXF specific code to JAX-RS 2.0 SPI compliant so that both old and new applications can use this library.

1.in CXF there is a way to set the receive timeout and connection timeout as follows

((HTTPConduit) config.getConduit()).getClient().setReceiveTimeout(timeout);

How do I port this to jaxrs2.0

2.The default implementation of resteasy 3.0.1 uses apache httpclient-4 (if i am not wrong) and singleclientconnmanager which causes ***connection busy*** error if not used properly. Is it good for production LIBRARY use (as you may not have control over client using this library)? Or how do I change it to work like CXF where I dont have to worry about the connections

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at this [Blog](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/GUVNOR-1809?_sscc=t) it may help you there are also few code snippets if u go to git hub please have a look.If not i can answer you showed some pointers

Comment: Im unable to find what im looking for, in that link. Can you please give me some more pointers/reference?